# Determining path to current wallpaper with pygtk (maybe X11?)

Tags: python, pygtk, x11

I would like to determine a user's wallpaper path with PyGTK.

If possible, I would like to **not** rely on a Desktop Environment's function to do this - this is because some users(like myself) do not use a DE. Because of this, I am wondering if you can use X11 or something else to determine the current wallpaper being used.

Comment: There's no notion of wallpaper in X11.  There's the root window and its background, but this is not associated with any kind of image residing in a filesystem.

Comment: More details on this please? How does X load it's background when it boots up? is it not from an image file?

Comment: X11 doesn't load any background image when it boots up. It can only use a simple pattern or a solid color. A DE or another client program, such as `xsetbg`, can load an image from disk (or synthesize one), blend it with dozen other images, apply any number of image-processing filters, convert it to a bitmap X11 understands, and set it as a background for the screen. X11 itself has no way to know how that bitmap was obtained.

Comment: I see now.
Do you happen to know if X stores a reference anywhere to this pixmap while it's in use? looks like i'll have to look into the source code to try and figure this out.

Comment: No! Background pixmaps are write-only. You can set them but not get them. See `man XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap`. There's no `XGetWindowBackgroundPixmap`.

Comment: Yep. furthermore i discovered that there's GetScreenPixmap, but it is to be used internally within the server and not available to clients =/
thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You MUST rely on a desktop environment, otherwise it is not possible, since X11 isn't supposed to handle such things as wallpapers. When you set a background image, an external program loads the image and sets it as the background pixmap of the root window. Therefore, unless the specific loading mechanism stores the image path somewhere, X11 itself will never know where the image file is located on the disk.

Comment: I see. Looking at the source code for Nitrogen, i notice that they convert a file to bitmap via GTK for X to use. So i assume when the system loads, such program as Nitrogen or Feh, will send the pixmap to X, yes?

Comment: @lyrae that's true. They load the image, convert it to a pixmap (not *bitmap*, which is slightly a different thing when talking about X11) and set that pixmap as the background for the root window.