# Retaining text rendered with Xft on the root window

Tags: c, x11, xlib

I am using Xft to draw some text on the root window, like

`XftDrawStringUtf8(drw, &xftc, f, 50, 50, (XftChar8 *)buf, x);`

After that, I would like to retain the text even after my program is killed, similar to `feh` or `xsetroot` behaviour. I looked at their sources and they both seem to

- save what have they drawn in a `Pixmap` structure
- embed it an `Atom` which they store in the server with `XChangeProperty`
- call `XSetCloseDownMode` with `RetainPermanent`.

Sample from `xsetroot`:

```
/* Free past incarnation if needed, and retain state if needed. */
static void
FixupState(void)
{
    Atom prop, type;
    int format;
    unsigned long length, after;
    unsigned char *data;

    if (!(DefaultVisual(dpy, screen)->class & Dynamic))
        unsave_past = 0;
    if (!unsave_past && !save_colors)
        return;
    prop = XInternAtom(dpy, "_XSETROOT_ID", False);
    if (unsave_past) {
        (void)XGetWindowProperty(dpy, root, prop, 0L, 1L, True, AnyPropertyType,
                                 &type, &format, &length, &after, &data);
        if ((type == XA_PIXMAP) && (format == 32) &&
            (length == 1) && (after == 0))
            XKillClient(dpy, *((Pixmap *)data));
        else if (type != None)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: warning: _XSETROOT_ID property is garbage\n",
                    program_name);
    }
    if (save_colors) {
        if (!save_pixmap)
            save_pixmap = XCreatePixmap(dpy, root, 1, 1, 1);
        XChangeProperty(dpy, root, prop, XA_PIXMAP, 32, PropModeReplace,
                        (unsigned char *) &save_pixmap, 1);
        XSetCloseDownMode(dpy, RetainPermanent);
    }
}
```

However, `xsetroot` has its `Pixmap` structure ready, saved with `XCopyPlane` before this. I am not sure how to save what I have drawn with Xft as a `Pixmap`.

Comment: Something should redraw the text if it's damaged. What would that be?

Comment: I am also not sure about what is redrawing the text, however this is the behaviour I observed reading the sources of `feh` and `xsetroot`. Here is how `feh` does it: https://github.com/derf/feh/blob/master/src/wallpaper.c

Comment: I am thinking about creating a Pixmap, then drawing on it using XftDrawCreateAlpha and pasting it onto the root screen with XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap. Wish Xft had documentation.

Comment: `xsetroot` and `feh` and any other such program set the *entire* root background. That's basically what `XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap` does, So what you end up with is just another full-size picture you use as a background. Are you asking how to create such a picture? Because calling `XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap` with it is trivial.

Comment: In addition, _XSETROOT_ID is a dummy 1x1 pixmap, only needed to identify a colormap. _XROOTPMAP_ID, if set. is the actual root pixmap (but not many modern WMs set it). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774388/determining-path-to-current-wallpaper-with-pygtk-maybe-x11).

Comment: I don't want a daemon, so that looks like the solution. The thing is, now I can draw a rectangle with `XftDrawRect()` and display it with `XSetBackgroundPixmap`, but calls to `XftDrawStringUtf8` seem to be useless.

Comment: If you want to change the entire background, that's what you do. But then it's unclear why any of the existing programs that do that is insufficient. Also, many DEs would overwrite your background periodically when set to slideshow wallpaper mode.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. However now there is another problem- perhaps deserves its own question.

Comment: `XftDrawRect()` seems to properly draw on the `Pixmap`, but not `XftDrawStringUtf8()`.

Comment: It accepts XftDraw, not Pixmap. Anyway it's a different question.

Comment: here is the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719258/xft-can-draw-rectangles-on-pixmaps-but-not-text)